# While Establishing SSL between IBM MQ and JMS client,recieving "com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9503: Channel negotiation failed" error

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, tls1.2

I'm trying to enable two way SSL encryption between JMS client and IBM MQ using a server conn channel called "KAU.CONN" , I have already generated client certificate and queue manager certificates using two different self signers. below are the steps I used to generate certificate and key stored in both side. when the MQ channels **SSLCAUTH** option set to **OPTIONAL** connectivity works fine. Appreciate any leads for the possible cause.

IBM MQ version = 9.2 (trial version)
JDK( jms client ) = 1.8

Error in eclipse:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9503: Channel negotiation failed. [3=KAU.CONN]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment(RemoteConnection.java:4464)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.receiveTSH(RemoteConnection.java:3199)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:895)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:416)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:312)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1761)
    ... 61 more
```

**SSL inplementation**

## QUEUE MANAGER

Commands used to create CA's certificate

```
runmqckm -keydb -create -db myCA.kdb -type cms  -pw mycakeypassword -stash
runmqckm -cert -create -db myCA.kdb -type cms -label "myCAcertificate" -dn "CN=demmoCA,O=DemmoOrg,OU=DemmoDepartment,L=DemmoLocation,C=UK" -expire 1000 -size 1024
runmqckm -cert -extract -db myCA.kdb -type cms -label "myCAcertificate" -target myCAcertfile.cer -format ascii -stashed
```

Issuing a certificate to a queue manager

```
runmqckm -keydb -create -db myqmgr.kdb -type cms -pw kautstpassword -stash
runmqckm -certreq -create -db myqmgr.kdb -type cms -dn "CN=KAU.TST,O=IBM,OU=WMQ,L=Hursley,C=UK" -label "ibmwebspheremqmyqmgr" -file kauqmgercsr.req -stashed
runmqckm -cert -sign -db myCA.kdb -label "myCAcertificate" -expire 365 -format ascii -file kauqmgercsr.req  -target kauqmgr.cer -stashed
runmqckm -cert -receive -db myqmgr.kdb -type cms -file kauqmgr.cer -stashed
```

## JMS CLIENT SIDE

Adding the queue manager's certificate(generated above) to client's keystore (after creating client's keystore)

```
keytool -keystore kautstclient.jks -genkey -alias winclientcert -storepass clientpassword
keytool -import -keystore kautstclient.jks -file myCAcertfile.cer -alias  myCAcertificate
```

creating a another CA's keys,certificate for jms client

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

generating certificate for client

```
keytool -certreq -v -alias winclientcert -file kauclient.csr -keypass clientpassword -storepass clientpassword -keystore kautstclient.jks
openssl x509 -req -in kauclient.csr -CA cert.pem -CAkey key.pem -CAcreateserial -out kauclientown.crt
keytool -import -v -alias kauclientowncert -file kauclientown.crt -keystore kautstclient.jks -keypass clientpassword -storepass clientpassword
```

**Finally Adding client certificate's signer certificate to the queue manager's kdb**

```
runmqckm -cert -add -db  myqmgr.kdb -file cert.pem -label kauclientsignercertificate
```

These are my JMS client's SSL property settings

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "clientpassword" );
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "clientpassword" );
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:\\mq-message-handler-1.0\\ssl\\kautstclient.jks" );
                    
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false" );
System.setProperty("jdk.security.allowNonCaAnchor","true");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","D:\\mq-message-handler-1.0\\ssl\\kautstclient.jks");
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");
```

Certificate details in client's keystore and qmgr's keystore

- please note my jms client is running in windows but I have used linux server to generate key/cert files and I'm more familiar with linux commands.

```
Certificates in database /tmp/client/kautstclient.jks: 
   winclientcert
   kauclientowncert
   mycacertificate


Certificates in database /var/mqm/qmgrs/KAU!TST/ssl/myqmgr.kdb:
   ibmwebspheremqmyqmgr
   "CN=demmoCA, O=DemmoOrg, OU=DemmoDepartment, L=DemmoLocation, C=UK"
   kauclientsignercertificate


[mqm@192 ssl]$ runmqakm -cert -list -db myqmgr.kdb -stashed
Certificates found
* default, - personal, ! trusted, # secret key
!       "CN=demmoCA, O=DemmoOrg, OU=DemmoDepartment, L=DemmoLocation, C=UK"
!       kauclientsignercertificate
-       ibmwebspheremqmyqmgr
```

Comment: Set up Chanel cipher spec to: "ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER" option. Try couple different TLS 1.2 from client side. Something old and surly implemented by client. If that works your cerficate configuration is ok on both sides and you are failing as client and mq are not able to do proper handshaking as algorithm negotiation is failing. I have seen similar errors with .Net clients on Windows and MQ on AIX because underlying OS-es between client and server would negotiate different TLS algorithm then one enforced by channel.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is not finding your trustStore.

Apparently, you can check whether the JVM is using the configured `trustStore` by using the following property: `-Djavax.net.debug=all` , which will turn on a debug message.

After the app starts, it will print out a message like:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|parallel-1|2021-04-17 21:25:13.827 CST|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: C:/path/to/the/trustStore
```

Comment: Can you please run `runmqckm -cert -list -db D:\mq-message-handler-1.0\ssl\kautstclient.jks` and `runmqckm -cert -list -db myqmgr.kdb` and add the output to your question?

Comment: Updated the question with the details

Comment: Run this to, note the different letter 3rd from end: `runmqakm -cert -list -db myqmgr.kdb`

Comment: updated the requested details

Comment: Could you run with `-details -label 'label value'` instead of `-list` for each label in each key store using runmqakm for the kdb and runmqckm for the jks and pricier the output.   Also try the ssl debug that Morag recommended to see if you can tell why it's not finding your client cert.